# How to set the font used in the autocomplete dropdown of a ComboBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, fonts, combobox, tamil

In my desktop application, I am using a tamil font (not unicode, but glyphs) in a ComboBox Font property.

It displays well when I type into it. But my auto suggestion in the DropDown box is displaying with the default font. How to change that font as well?

```
Private Sub Billing_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
  If My.Settings.Options_Display_UseOtherLanguage Then
       CustomerNameCombo.Font = My.Settings.Options_Display_OtherLanguageFont
  End If
End Sub
```

[image: tamil in vb.net]

I am using .NET Framework v4.0

Comment: Are you setting the font programatically or through the designer properties?

Comment: programatically.. because this is user's preference.. @Jacooobley even if I set it through properties, same effect..

Comment: Ok can I see the code please, so I can play around with it.

Comment: I dont *think* you can, these are set in the browser, and I assume in the language of the computer

Comment: @Prisoner this is not a web application. this is a desktop app

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Are you using custom source for auto suggestion? If so the source should also be in the same language. (i.e)in this case, auto suggestion source should also be in tamil.

Else set `AutoCompleteSource` to `ListItems`, where the datasource is in tamil

Comment: the source will be in English only. I just need to change the font (not the language) in the dropdown area..

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [DropDownStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle.aspx) property of the ComboBox. You should be able to set the font for your ComboBox in the DrawItem event. The MSDN link I provided has an example that should point you in the right direction. Hope it helps.

Comment: DrawItem event is called "only" when you click the button in the comboxbox which shows all the items in the dropdownlist. DrawItem is not fired when the autocomplete dropdown is shown.